# React: conditional dependency on useEffect? Or how to prevent redundancy?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, refactoring, react-hooks, use-effect

If I have a `React hook` that does not need always to be linked with the `auth` state (as a `useEffect` dependency, how can I **conditionally** remove this dependency, or any other way to prevent **redundancy** and thus avoid creating a second almost identical hook?

```js
export const useHookAuth = () => {

  // useless code

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!auth.user) return

    // even uselesser code
  }, [auth.user])

  return ['with auth dependency']
}
```

```js
export const useHookWithoutAuth = () => {

  // the same useless code

  useEffect(() => {
    // identical even uselesser code
  }, [])

  return ['without auth dependency']
}
```

EDIT: more in detail, in this example the hook `useExample` takes care of "this" auth, but this is redundant since it is already done before by the component `Content`

However, this hook is used elsewhere where it does have to take into account this auth

The question is how to avoid duplicating the hook if I only want not to have the hook linked to auth?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const AuthContext = createContext(null);
const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
const useAuthProvider = () => {
  const [access, setAccess] = useState(0);
  return { access, setAccess };
};

const useExample = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth && !auth.access) return;
    setContent("fetched content");

    // even uselesser code
  }, [auth]);

  return [content];
};

const Button = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        auth.setAccess(1);
      }}
    >
      clickme
    </button>
  );
};

const Content = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const [content] = useExample();
  return <h2>{(auth && auth.access && content) || "restricted"}</h2>;
};

export default function App() {
  const authProvider = useAuthProvider();

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authProvider}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <Button />
        <Content />
      </div>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-pike-ng4wg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Why not extract the common code into a separate function and use it in both hooks? You also could set deps conditionally, like `useEffect(..., [auth?.user])`

Comment: Is it a possibility? to use conditional dependencies?

Comment: yes, in the sense, that you can create the dependency array dynamically / conditionally. At the end of the day, React will compare all items (referential equality), and if something changed, invoke a possible clean up and re-invoke `useEffect`.

Comment: So given `[auth?.user]`, the dependency would either be `user` or `undefined`. Say, it changes from `user` to `undefined`, React would 1) call clean-up, 2) call `useEffect` only once  (until deps would change again). `[undefined]` is same as `[]` dep.

Comment: Great, didn't know it could be done  If you have time, you could rephrase it as an answer and I'd close the issue, otherwise I'll do it later, and big thanks!!

Comment: It's still not really clear to me, what you are *actually* trying to achieve, without having understood the full use case of `useHookAuth` hook. Also possible: pass an optional `auth` arg to `useHookAuth`, set `useEffect` dep to `[auth]`, drop `useHookWithoutAuth` and check for auth.user in the effect cb. You seem to already have found a suitable solution, so feel free to post it here yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on @ford04 comments, I could use a conditional dependency on useEffect

It however goes at the cost of having a warning

** In this example it doesn't feel logical to execute always the hook without an access being granted, but its only use is to show that a conditional dependency in `useEffect` is possible (which I didn't know)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const AuthContext = createContext(null);
const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
const useAuthProvider = () => {
  const [access, setAccess] = useState(0);
  return { access, setAccess };
};

const useExample = withoutAuth => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(auth);
    console.log(!withoutAuth);
    if (auth && !auth.access && !withoutAuth) return;
    setContent("fetched content");
    console.log("done"); // this is executed always, regardless of auth

    // even uselesser code
  }, [withoutAuth ? null : auth]);

  return [content];
};

const Button = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        auth.setAccess(1);
      }}
    >
      Fetch
    </button>
  );
};

const Content = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const [content] = useExample(1); // here I say NOT to implement auth
  return <h2>{(auth && auth.access && content) || "restricted"}</h2>;
};

export default function App() {
  const authProvider = useAuthProvider();

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authProvider}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <Button />
        <Content />
      </div>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-currying-jcenj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you please share the details of the **warning** when the dependency array isn't predefined? Thanks!
@GWorking